# serverside vs client

Tags: sql, sql-server

First let me say i am only a novice programmer, and by no means an sql guru. We have an app at work that is and has been under heavy dev from the vendor for sometime (2+ years). It runs as a MSSQL instance on one of our servers, and there is a client install for the desktops. The client software is making direct sql calls to the database.(it also has a local mysql instance to handle the client settings) there is 6-12 ports that had to be opened up for the communication. Looking at the sql manager, i can see direct sql calls from various clients.

Seems to me this is entirely the wrong approach. the closest thing i have done to this, was a webpage + php+ mysql. The webpage would make requests, and all the processing would be serverside, then simply display the results. The sluggishness my users feel i think is from the clientside request+ processing of the sql data.

ps: i realize that if they have not done  it by now, switching to another paradigm seems out of the question. i just want to know if i am way off base.

Comment: *"Seems to me this is entirely the wrong approach."* - Can you explain why?  Having a local MySQL instance for "client settings" certainly seems odd to me.  But what's wrong with a central database with applications accessing it?  *"The sluggishness my users feel i think is from the clientside request+ processing of the sql data."* - Have you gathered any metrics or done any profiling/debugging to confirm this?  Don't optimize unless you know where the bottleneck is.  What makes you think that _not_ offloading processing to the clients in general would speed anything up?

Comment: Open management studio and click the Tools menu, then SQL Server Profiler.  Point it at your production database while a user is feeling "sluggish".  I imagine what you are going to see is a bunch of single requests. select * from table where id = 1; select * from table where id = 2; select * from table where id = 3; etc etc.  

If that is not the case, check the read/write times and let us have  a little more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are way off base.

The client side has much more processing power.

Consider the case of one server and 5 clients.  Even is the server has 3 times the power of a client the clients as a whole are still 5:3 more powerful.

If the application is sluggish it was probably poorly written. You need to investigate the root cause.  Client / Server is a leading practice in design, I'm guessing it is not the root cause.  It might be badly implemented or there might be other reasons.  Your comment about having a local mysql sounds very fishy to me -- there should be no need for this.

Comment: it is a closed source, paid for app. but just from some of the things i have seen,seems poorly implemented. ie: the local mysql instance, and in the main client, the bottm section was written in a different programming language (the vendor told us this), and it is HEAVILY dependent on local client graphics drivers (on crappy vid cards the bottom section simply does not load), and it feels liek they are doing directx/gaming type video calls, when it is all 2d text info. will log into the sql server and provide more info in a bit.